# Azure OMS alert - Send chart as part of OMS alert to email

Tags: azure, alert, azure-oms, oms

We can get logs based on OMS query in Azure in table as well as chart form. I would like to generate an OMS alert for the same but share the chart instead of the table result to email.

I am exploring Azure and would like to know if it possible to do so? If Yes, how can we achieve the same as I could post table but was unable to get chart as part of the email?

Answer (score 0):

The feature to include chart as part of default alert email body or the feature to customize or configure alert email body format is currently not supported. If interested, I recommend to raise feedback [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/602299-azure-monitor-alert-management) in UserVoice / feedback forum. [Here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/602299-azure-monitor-alert-management?query=alert%20email) are the related feature requests that are already raised which you may upvote that are of interest. In general, Azure feature / product team would check feasibility of a feature request, prioritize against existing feature backlog, add them in roadmap as appropriate and would announce and/or update the related Azure document once a feature request is addressed.